# Why helicity for massless particles is Lorentz invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, helicity, invariants

By definition helicity is projection of spin onto the 3 momentum.

$$h={\bf J} \cdot   {\mathbf{P }}  $$
where ${\mathbf{P }}=(P_1,P_2,P_3)$ is the momentum operator and ${\mathbf{J }}=(J_1,J_2,J_3)$ the angular operator.

Now under a Lorentz transformation massless particles transform like this:
$$U(\Lambda)|p,\sigma\rangle=e^{i\theta\sigma}| \Lambda p,\sigma\rangle.$$

As we can see the momentum is changing but the spin not.

Suppose  that state  $|p,\sigma\rangle$ is a state of helicity $\sigma$ such that we have
$$h|p,\sigma\rangle=J_3P_3|p,\sigma\rangle=\sigma p_3|p,\sigma\rangle  $$

But for the state $U(\Lambda)|p,\sigma\rangle=e^{i\theta\sigma}| \Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$, we would have
$$h|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=\sigma p'_3e^{i\theta\sigma}| \Lambda p,\sigma\rangle| $$
So for conservation of helicity we would require $p_3=p'_3$ which is not always the case.

So why do people say that helicity is Lorentz invariant?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli%E2%80%93Lubanski_pseudovector#Helicity_representations).

Comment: possible dup.? [Mathematical proof on helicity of a massive fermion is not Lorentz invariant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/408135/84967).

Comment: The answer in the link you gave is good  but the definition   of helicity is different

Answer (score 5):

Your formula for the helicity operator is **wrong**; this should already be clear at the level of dimensional analysis. The correct formula is (cf. Refs 1&2)
$$
h=\frac{{\bf J} \cdot   {\mathbf{P }}}{\color{red}{|\mathrm{P}|}}
$$
where $|\mathrm{P}|$ denotes the norm of ${\mathbf{P }}$. Acting on your state with $h$ yields no factors of $p_3$, and so the "paradox" is resolved.

**References.**

1. Schwartz - *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model* §11.1.
2. Ticciati - *Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians* §7.8.

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Can you try again please? I have no idea what you're trying to say. (First you have an operator, then a state, then a tensor product of states; none of these can be equal to each other...)

Comment: sorry  computer problem

Comment: Suppose that we have $\frac{{\bf J} \cdot   {\mathbf{P }}}{\color{red}{|\mathrm{P}|}}|p,\sigma\rangle=\sigma|p,\sigma\rangle$. Now suppose that our transformation is a rotation in the $x$ axis than  $\frac{{\bf J} \cdot   {\mathbf{P }}}{\color{red}{|\mathrm{P}|}}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=(\frac{p'_2\mathbf{J_2 }}{p_3}+\frac{p'_3 \sigma}{p_3})|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle.$ Is $(\frac{p'_2\mathbf{J_2 }}{p_3}+\frac{p'_3 \sigma}{p_3})|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$ equal to $\sigma|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$?

Comment: $\frac{{\bf J} \cdot   {\mathbf{P }}}{|\mathrm{P}|}$ is evidently a scalar under rotations...Elicity cannot change under rotations, this is also true if the particle is massive.

Comment: How can i proof that?

Comment: Just apply the unitary representation of rotations and use the fact that $J$ and $P$ are 3-vectors under the action of it whereas $|P|$ is a scalar....