# Helicity under rotation

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, group-representations, helicity

Suppose  that the  state $|p,\sigma\rangle$ (for a massless particle) has 3 momentum ${\bf p}=p_3$ (that is the  momentum is in the $z$ direction) and that $J_3|p,\sigma\rangle=\sigma|p,\sigma\rangle$ 
where ${\mathbf{P }}=(P_1,P_2,P_3)$ is the momentum operator and ${\mathbf{J }}=(J_1,J_2,J_3)$ the angular momentum operator. Than

$$\frac{{\bf J} \cdot   {\mathbf{P }}}{{|\mathbf{P}|}}|p,\sigma\rangle=\frac{{\bf J_3}   {\mathbf{P_3 }}}{{|\mathbf{P}|}}|p,\sigma\rangle =\sigma|p,\sigma\rangle$$

Now suppose that we make  a rotation around the $x$ axis than for a massless particle the state should transform like this 
$$U(\Lambda)|p,\sigma\rangle=e^{i\theta\sigma}| \Lambda p,\sigma\rangle.$$

Since $\mathbf{J_2}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=0$,
how can we proof that $$\frac{{\bf J} \cdot   {\mathbf{P }}}{{|\mathbf{P }|}}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=\frac{p'_3 \mathbf{J_3 }}{|\mathbf{P }|}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=\frac{p'_3 \sigma}{|\mathbf{P }|}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle.$$

is equal to

$$\sigma|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$$

or since rotation leaves the norm of a vector invariant,  that is the same as to proof that
$$\frac{p'_3}{|\mathbf{P }|}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=\frac{p'_3}{p_3}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$$

is equal to

$$|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$$

Comment: Why is $\boldsymbol J\cdot\boldsymbol P=J_3P_3$?

Comment: Because  i am assuming that the $|p,\sigma\rangle$ has momentum $p_3$ (in the $z$ direction) and angular momentum $\sigma=\sigma_3$ (in the $z$ direction)

Comment: if $|p,\sigma\rangle$ has momentum in the $z$ direction, then $\frac{1}{|P|}|p,\sigma\rangle=\frac{1}{p_3}|p,\sigma\rangle$, and the factors of $p_3$ disappear.

Comment: You are right but the norm of a vector is rotation invariant and so  $\frac{1}{|P|}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=\frac{1}{p_3}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle $ and then we would have $\frac{p'_3}{|\mathbf{P }|}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=\frac{p'_3}{p_3}|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$. But the factor $\frac{p'_3}{p_3}$ does not disapear

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is overlooking the fact that the parameter $\sigma$ measures the helicity referring to the **actual direction** of ${\bf p}$.

Therefore, following again the first (correct) part of your reasoning where $p$ was directed along $x_3$, simply replacing the unit vector ${\bf e}_3$ for the rotated axis $\Lambda {\bf e}_3$ you find that  $|\Lambda p, \sigma\rangle$ satisfies $$\frac{{\bf J}\cdot {\bf P}}{|{\bf P}|}|\Lambda p, \sigma\rangle = (\Lambda {\bf e}_3)\cdot {\bf J}|\Lambda p, \sigma\rangle = \sigma |\Lambda p, \sigma\rangle\:.$$ As 
$\Lambda {\bf e}_3$ generally admits components along **both** $x_2$ and $x_3$, you **cannot** argue that $$J_2 |\Lambda p, \sigma\rangle = 0,$$ $$J_3 |\Lambda p, \sigma\rangle =\sigma |\Lambda p, \sigma \rangle,$$ and your claim does not follows.

Comment: Suppose that $\Lambda {\bf e}_3=\cos\theta{\bf e}_3+\sin\theta{\bf e}_2$
i am not seeing why $(\cos\theta J_3+\sin\theta J_2)|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle=(\sigma \cos\theta +\sin\theta J_2)|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$ is equal to $\sigma |\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$

Comment: By definition. It is the definition of the states $|p,\sigma\rangle$.  Your second identity above is *wrong* $J_3|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle \neq \sigma|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$. That is the same mistake you took in the post.

Comment: If states do transform like this $U(\Lambda)|p,\sigma\rangle=e^{i\theta\sigma}| \Lambda p,\sigma\rangle.$ that means that the $z$ component of angular momentum does not change so we would have $ J_3|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle =\sigma|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$ or am i understanding it wrong?

Comment: $|p,\sigma\rangle$ has the property that $\sigma$ is the component along ${\bf p}$ of ${\bf J}$. If ${\bf p}$ is directed along ${\bf e}_3$, then $\sigma$ is the value of the component $J_3$. Therefore, keeping ${\bf p}$ as said, if $\Lambda$ is a rotation $\Lambda p$ has **not** spatial components directed along ${\bf e}_3$ and consequently $\sigma$ cannot coincide to the component $J_3$ any more.

Comment: Please, stop insisting on your erroneous claims and try to focus on  what I am trying to communicate you. Otherwise this discussion is useless.

Comment: I think that i am misunderstanding  something here. Is the $J_3$ the $z$  component of the rotated frame or the $z$ component of the original frame?

Comment: In my answer and in my comments $_3$ (and in your question I think)  always denotes the third component referred to  the fix laboratory frame.

Comment: But in your question above you implicitly assumed the other convention.

Comment: In this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408135/mathematical-proof-on-helicity-of-a-massive-fermion-is-not-lorentz-invariant the helicity  is defined as the third component of its angular momentum in a special reference frame: $J_z |\boldsymbol p^\star,\sigma\rangle:=\sigma|\boldsymbol p^\star,\sigma\rangle$ and in the end of the answer the author says that Lorentz transformations do not change the value of $\sigma$ so if Lorentz transformations do not change the value of $\sigma$  than shouldn't we always have $J_z|\Lambda 
 p,\sigma\rangle=\sigma|\Lambda p,\sigma\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, that definition is in agreement with my answer and comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97484/discussion-between-amilton-moreira-and-valter-moretti).

Comment: Sorry I  must stop here, I am busy now.